# Is there a way to know in the method webViewDidFinishLoad: which url was loaded?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

My problem is that I only request one url request to load, but the server makes the web view load a bunch of other stuff.

There is a delegate method called [webViewDidFinishLoad:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) that passes as a parameter the webview that finished to load.

The question is: Is there any way to know which request finished to load?

Comment: Is `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` called for these others?

Comment: yes, but the order in which they are loaded may not be the same in which they end being loaded.

Comment: I might be wrong in my last comment if only one request is done at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have just 1 way to know the actual request in your webview:

```
NSURLRequest *request = webview.request;
```

and you can monitor the request that start by the method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Comment: Assuming webview.request is the last request loaded, this would be the right answer. thanks! Do you know if only 1 request can be loaded at a time or if multiple request can be loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Hope for you just 1 :) But i suggest to read the Apple documentation about the method shouldStartLoadWithRequest that is called when webview load frame etc.

Comment: Then, the correct way of doing it is to store the request being loaded (retrieved from the shouldStartLoadWithRequest:) in a variable, since webview.request is only the request done by the user (as I've confirmed: http://s29.postimg.org/u44zjvrja/Captura_de_pantalla_2014_05_09_a_la_s_10_22_39.jpg). Please update the answer.

Comment: hmmm, my log also appears to show that more than one request is being loaded at a time, since there are multiple "will load"s followed by multiple "end loading"s.